# How do I restore an old version of navigation or the communication site as a whole

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, communication-site

I have a site I've been working on for weeks and the client just recently changed the navigation (which contained hundreds of links).

Is there a way i can restore a previous version of the navigation or the communication site as a whole?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge, there is no option to restore an old version of navigation in the communication site.